# PHP- Delete images with the name "example"

Tags: php

How can I delete images in a folder that for example all have the name "john" in them. I am making a temporary image folder and I want to erase all of the users data on the temp folder after they're done.
Thanks.

Comment: Just use the `unlink()` function.

Comment: @PHPglue This looks like a HW question, thus nothing has been presented (no effort whatsoever besides the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of PHP's built in [DirectoryIterator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php) to iterate across all the files in the `images/` directory you want to modify.

```
$name = 'John';
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('images'); //In this case the images directory
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        //Is a valid file name
        $filename = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        //Now you have access to the filename make appropriate modifications. Below is a quick naive demonstration. 
        if (strpos($filename, $name)) {
            //We have fulfilled the 'John' condition, delete the file
            unlink('images/' . $filename);
        } 
    }
}
```

You may need to modify the variables and directory names accordingly based on `absolute` or `relative` pathing to your situation. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions to (if relevant).

Comment: I changed some stuff but it still doesn't work. The temp folder is outside of the PHP folder. Is this the correct way to use it?

    $name = $log_username;
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname('../tempUploads'));
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
      if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {$filename = $fileinfo->getFilename(); modifications
        if (strpos($filename, $name)) {
          //It exists, delete the file
          unlink('images/' . $filename);
        }
     }
  }

Comment: I wouldn't use `relative` pathing, the error you're probably getting is because of the wrong `path` you are giving it. Also, you don't need `dirname` if you are doing it like that

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and absolutely specify the path. Remove `dirname` since that's extraneous in this situation (unless you were specifying a file in the directory you wanted to loop through)

Comment: I don't get any errors, it just doesn't delete anything.

Comment: Try this `unlink` instead: `unlink($fileinfo->getPathname());`

Comment: It's definitely something that I put wrong. Because your code seems fine. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<?php
$NameToDelete = $_GET['name'];  //ex: file.php?name=john
$Folder = "/images/"; //The folder you want to delete from

$FileType = array(  //All the filetypes (in this case some image types
'jpg',
'png',
'bmp',
'jpeg'
);

foreach($FileType as $Type){//For EACH filetype as type

$Link = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."$Folder".$NameToDelete."."."$Type"; //path

@unlink($Link); //DELETE - using @ to not get any errors
echo "Deleted: $Link<br/>";  //Print
}
```